# Reducing the sizeof a vector using custom allocator?

Tags: c++, c++11, sizeof, stdvector, allocator

I'm using Linux on a 64-bit machine and I use g++4.8.
The `sizeof` operator applied on a `std::vector` returns :

```
sizeof(std::vector<float>) = 24
sizeof(std::vector<double>) = 24
sizeof(std::vector<long double>) = 24
```

My question is : is there any way to create a vector with a smaller size based on the fact that my application will never need vectors of more than `1 GB` of elements ? Because optimally, I could have a vector of 16 bytes : the pointer to the beginning (8 bytes), the current size (4 bytes) and the current capacity (4 bytes). Do I have to recode my own vector from scratch or can I reduce the size with a custom allocator ?

This size is very critical for me as I work on supercomputers with more than 100 TB of memory, and every byte I can gain on my basic classes could finally save several TB of memory.

Comment: Sounds like nonsense to me... "every byte I can gain on my basic classes could finally save several TB of memory" if you have several *millions of million* vectors yes... that's not elements in vectors, but vectors themselves.  You say your vectors will never have more than 1GB of elements... if you have anything like number of vectors you claim, they'll can't average more than a few hundred bytes and therefore a few hundred elements given the 100TB-scale of total memory you talk about.

Comment: Yes I have potentially billions of vectors distributed over thousands of cores. I will try to rethink the implementation, but it is not easy.

Comment: If that's the case, you'll want to look very carefully at whether your heap allocation library is wasting much additional space per vector.  It sounds like a lot of your vectors could be empty or have one element a lot of the time, so if you can spare a couple sentinel values (perhaps NaNs, infinity), a single value could potentially encode the empty, non-sentinel single element and sentinel for needing a proper vector.

Comment: Billions of vectors of sizes up to 1GB each is a problem that goes far beyond whether the vector object takes up 16 or 24 bytes. "Billion" equals "tera", so if you have a billion vectors of _only_ 100 bytes (25 floats or 12 doubles, respectively) in size, that's your 100TiB of RAM gone. Don't even think of fragmentation.

Comment: @Damon: billion's a bit vague (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Billion) but in IT I think the 1,000,000,000 meaning much more common than the 1,000,000,000,000 now - so my calculations above at on billion bytes = gigabyte not tera.  But, same fundamental point... it doesn't add up for very many of the vectors to have many elements.

Comment: My calculator (Google) tells me that 2^64/(10^10*1024*1024*1024) ≈ 1.71, so you've exhausted more than half of the 64bit address space with this dataset, too. Assuming a "normal" 50:50 kernel/user split, this can only work at all if the machine uses 128bit addressing. Which, however, would mean that `vector` necessarily needs to be bigger, too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, you can't.

The original idea with allocators was that they could define objects for pointers and reference types to the data. However, that's not really allowed anymore; `allocator<T>::pointer` must be `T*`, and containers are freely allowed to assume that it is.

So if you truly need a vector to use some kind of compact pointer representation or something, you're going to have to implement one yourself.

The standard library containers are good defaults for most uses. But for those with specialized needs, you may have to replace them with something else. That would appear to be the case here.

Comment: C++11 has relaxed the requirement that `allocator<T>::pointer` must be `T*`.  It must be a random access iterator, satisfy the `NullablePointer` requirements and meet the other requirements of Table 28 - Allocator requirements.

Comment: @HowardHinnant: So how can `std::vector::data` return a `T*` instead of `allocator<T>::pointer`?

Comment: libc++ (http://libcxx.llvm.org) has an implementation that does this.  There's a cute trick of turning a `smart_pointer<T>` into a `T*` using `operator->()`.  That being said, I am still working on making libc++ completely conforming to arbitrary `allocator<T>::pointer` (working on it as I type this).

Comment: @HowardHinnant: I'm interested in what the standard says about this though. If `pointer` is just a random-access iterator (and therefore there is no guarantee that the `T*` you get from them are *contiguous*), how is it possible for `std::vector::data` to work? Or really, any `std::vector` function to work? Or, more to the point, does the standard *require* that implementations of `vector` allow for this possibility?

Comment: I would think that if your `allocator<T>::pointer` didn't guarantee contiguous storage that using such an allocator for vector would violate 23.3.7.1/p1 which describes the contiguous requirement for vector.

Comment: @HowardHinnant: But there's nothing in the standard that says that the allocator passed to a `std::vector` must allocate storage contiguously. Does `vector` add any requirements to its allocator besides those from Table 28? If not, that seems to lead to a contradiction: the allocator used with a `vector` is not required to allocate contiguous memory (since allocators only have to provide random-access allocations). Yet `vector` is required to provide contiguous memory, even though it's the allocator that must fulfill that requirement.

Comment: This is always one of your options: http://cplusplus.github.io/LWG/lwg-active.html#submit_issue

Answer (score 1):

Vectors are traditionally implemented using three pointers (begin, end, and end of storage).
The only way to shrink them is to change the internal representation indeed.

Answer (score 0):

This size is built in to the `vector`'s implementation, and you can't reduce that conveniently (building in 32-bit mode would of course reduce the size due to smaller pointer sizes).

Perhaps if you're using trillions of `vectors` in your code you might want to try to reduce *that* number (combine them into a larger `vector`?) rather than trying to shave a couple bytes off each one.

Answer (score 0):

There is something to clear up: vector size and capacity data become relatively very very small when vector size grows.

Lets say you have a double vector of size 1 million. Size and capacity data will still occupy 8 bytes in total and it is quite minute compared to the main data the vector holds.

If you frequently use very small sized vectors like from 1 to 50, then you can write a wrapper to arrays and use it and std vectors may not be a good choice for small sized data groups . I do not know whether your RAM is 100TB or it is just your hard drive capacity but keeping many small sized data structures may not be a good idea while it can result in severe `memory fragmentation`s.

Comment: Yes the avaible RAM can be up to 300TB (HDD up to ... several PB). The problem I try to solve is fundamentally fragmented, but I will try to trade memory size versus memory operations (access/insertion).